# ¿Cómo puedo leer los campos contenidos dentro de un array (que mando por medio ajax) en un archivo php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, array

Tengo un array en javascript que contendría la siguiente estructura:

```
var productos = [
    {"nombre" : "televisor", "descripcion" : "televisor 29 pulgadas", etc},
    {//acá abría más objetos}
];
```

Ahora, mi duda viene al querer mandar este array con múltiples objetos internos a un archivo php por medio de AJAX. 
Leí algo hacerca de codificar todo el array a JSON y decodificarlo en un archivo PHP. Sin embargo, no funcionó en mi caso porque mi array es diferente al del ejemplo de la página en la cual vi eso. Entonces, ¿Cómo podría enviar este tipo de array a php y luego poder acceder a cada atributo y valor? (para posteriormente guardar los valores en una base de datos).

La manera en que tengo que enviar los datos al php es la siguiente:

```
if(productos.length >= 1){
        var parametros = {
            "id_cliente" : $("#clienteSeleccionado").val(), //input hidden con el valor del id del cliente seleccionado
            "productos" : productos //array js común con objetos JSON dentro
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "peticiones/crearSolicitudDeEnvio.php",
            data: parametros,
            beforeSend: function(){
                $("#loading").css("display", "block");
            },
            success: function(respuesta){
                $("#loading").css("display", "none");
                console.log(respuesta);
            }
         )};
}
```

Obviamente, hay más código dentro del "success". Pero para poder probar si se envía y recibe correctamente el objeto JSON que contiene un integer y un array con otros objetos JSON dentro, solo posteo un "console.log(respuesta)" en este código.

Edición:

A productos lo mandé como JSON.stringify(productos) y lo recibí en php como json_decode($_POST["productos"]). Y me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\envios\peticiones\crearSolicitudDeEnvio.php
Array
```

No se cuál sería el error que me da. Supongo que me indica que no se puede hacer dicho json_decode.

Comment: Normalmente eso se haría con JSON, incluso en contextos muy complejos. ¿Què es lo que no dejaría hacerlo en JSON?

Comment: haz `console.log(JSON.stringify(productos))` ?  y comprueba que el servidor acepta ese string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probá codificarlo en js de la siguiente forma:

```
JSON.stringify(productos)
```

Y luego  en  PHP  hacer  lo  siguiente :

```
$productos = json_decode($_POST['data']);
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Primero para enviar la data a través de una consulta AJAX, podemos hacer lo siguiente (ejemplo Jquery)

```
var data = {'data': id};
$.ajax({
   url: 'dondeRecibire.php',
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: data
})
```

Le enviamos la petición a `dondeRecibire.php`, en este archivo, recibimos la petición mediante POST (como se indica en el ejemplo), así que simplemente puedes darle `var_dump($_POST)` y con esto puedes trabajar con la data enviada, luego, al momento de retornar.

```
echo json_encode(array("variableResultado"=>$retorno));
```

Nótese que 'retornamos' un `echo` y no un `return`; en caso de utilizar algún framework, la mayoría de estos traen helpers para retornar (por ejemplo, en Symfony2 usas la clase Response y retornas `return new Response(json_encode($retorno))`.

También, para manipular los objetos después de la respuesta del AJAX, puedes usar

```
success: function (response) {    
   console.log(response)
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! En mi código mando dos variables; una es un id perteneciente al cliente al cual se le van a enviar los productos contenidos en el array, y la otra es el propio array de productos. Por lo que, aunque se ve muy tentadora esa manera de enviar el array, no podría. Porque una variable dentro del objeto JSON es un id y la otra es un array js normal con objetos JSON dentro. Ahora lo agrego en la pregunta para mostrarlo.